# pre_get_posts filter using numeric meta_query comparison (from dates)

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, date, pre-get-posts, customization

I have an expiry date ACF field `'post_end_date'` which has been applied to multiple post types, including `'post'`.

I'm trying to filter out any posts, across the entire site, where today's date is greater than the value `'post_end_date'`; in other words the post has expired. I've checked that `'post_end_date'` value returns a number in the same format as `date('Ymd')`. e.g.

```
echo date('Ymd'); // returns 20161128 for today
echo get_field('post_end_date'); // returns 20161127 for yesterday
```

I figured the best way would be to just do a numerical comparison between today's date and `'post_end_date'` value.

This is my code:

```
  function expiry_filter($query) {

    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :

      $today = $expire = date('Ymd');

      if ( get_field('post_end_date') ) :
        $expire = get_field('post_end_date');
      endif;

      $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        array(
         'key'     => $expire,
         'value'   => $today,
         'compare' => '<',
         'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        )
      ));

    endif;
  }
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'expiry_filter' );
```

At this point, I was just trying to get it to work for the `'post'` post type. I have checked that I haven't used the wrong 'compare' operator. I've tried with and without the `$query->is_main_query()` conditional.

The result I'm getting with the code above is ALL posts are being filtered out.

Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check your values. `'key' => $expire` will result in `'key' => 20161128` or something. Shouldn't it be `'key' => 'post_end_date'`?

Comment: Good point @FabianMarz ! So, when making the adjustment I now get only the posts that should be filtered out showing with < as the comparator, which makes sense. So it is matching the meta_query now, but how do I invert it to remove those that match, rather than remove everything that doesn't match? Swapping compare operator to >= filters out everything

Comment: `>=` should to the trick. Have you checked your values? `get_field` will refer to the current post which can lead to unexpected results as you hook in the main query. So maybe there is no post from today?

Comment: OK. I follow you @FabianMarz. Last question: How do I adjust to include posts where `post_end_date` is not set? Or do I do an `if ( get_field('post_end_date') ):` around the `$query->set`? If you submit as an answer, I will mark your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you an issue in your meta query, as you set the key to `20161126` or similar. Instead `key` should be filled with your meta key `post_end_date`. [Meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Usage) also support multiple arrays to combine your query to also include posts where the meta key is not set. The example would be something like the following:

```php
function expiry_filter($query) {
  if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $expire = get_field('post_end_date') ? : date('Ymd');
    $query->set( 'meta_query', [
      'relation' => 'OR',
      [
       'key'     => 'post_end_date',
       'value'   => $expire,
       'compare' => '>=',
       'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
      ],
      [
       'key'     => 'post_end_date',
       'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
      ],
    ]);
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'expiry_filter' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `meta_key`, `meta_value` and `meta_compare`?

```
function expiry_filter( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :

        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'post_end_date' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', date('Ymd') );
        $query->set( 'meta_compare', '>' );

    endif;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'expiry_filter' );
```

Or maybe trying to use the `DATE` type when using `meta_query`?

```
function expiry_filter( $query ) {

  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :

      $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
          array(
              'key'     => 'post_end_date',
              'value'   => date( 'Ymd' ),
              'compare' => '>=',
              'type'    => 'DATE'
          )
      ) );

  endif;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'expiry_filter' );
```

Or just using the cleaned up version of your function

```
function expiry_filter( $query ) {

  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) :

      $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
          array(
              'key'     => 'post_end_date',
              'value'   => date( 'Ymd' ),
              'compare' => '>',
              'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
          )
      ) );

  endif;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'expiry_filter' );
```