# query posts in functions.php and update a field

Tags: wp-query, functions, advanced-custom-fields, post-meta

I'm having problems querying posts in `functions.php`. This is mainly to update posts in the back-end, not to show a query on the front end. I'm trying to get all posts that use the status post format and update a meta field if a variable is true.

My code:

```
function status_alerts($query) { //start function
global $post; // set the global
$args = array( // all posts in the status post format
    'posts_per_page' =>  -1,
    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'post-format-status' ),
    'operator'=> 'IN'
);
$alert_query = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $alert_query->have_posts() ) : $alert_query->the_post(); //query post
    if (get_post_meta( $post_id, 'breaking_news_status', true ) == 'active') { // if the post has a meta field called 'active'
        if ((get_post_meta($post_id, 'status_time_duration', true) + + get_the_time('U')) < date( 'U', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) )) { // if the 'status_time_duration' plus the publish date is greater than the current time
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'breaking_news_status', 'archive'); // add a check to 'archive' to 'breaking_news_status'
        }
    }
endwhile;
}
```

Comment: The `$post_id` is not defined in your code. Did you mean to use `$post->ID` or maybe do `$post_id = get_the_ID();` ?

Comment: changed to `$post->ID` still didn't update.

Comment: Never mind, used the wrong function. Should have used ‘wp_post_update’

Comment: Ok, but if you're just updating a metadata and not other post fields, then `get_post_meta()` would do the job; there's no need to use `wp_update_post()`. Also, you could use meta query - add `'meta_key' => 'status_time_duration', 'meta_value' => 'active'` to the `$args` array to query for posts that have the metadata `status_time_duration` set to `active`. That way, you wouldn't need the `if (get_post_meta( $post_id, 'breaking_news_status', true ) == 'active')`.

Comment: And I left out `add_action( 'init', 'status_alerts' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace $post_id with get_the_id();

```
function status_alerts($query) { //start function
  global $post; // set the global
  $args = array( // all posts in the status post format
    'posts_per_page' =>  -1,
    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'post-format-status' ),
    'operator'=> 'IN'
  );
   $alert_query = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $alert_query->have_posts() ) : $alert_query->the_post(); //query post
    if (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'breaking_news_status', true ) == 'active') { // if the post has a meta field called 'active'
        if ((get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'status_time_duration', true) + + get_the_time('U')) < date( 'U', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) )) { // if the 'status_time_duration' plus the publish date is greater than the current time
            update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'breaking_news_status', 'archive'); // add a check to 'archive' to 'breaking_news_status'
        }
    }
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: changed to `$post->ID`, still didn't update the post

Comment: try get_the_ID() instead of $post->ID as i mentioned above code .

Comment: You left out `add_action( 'init', 'status_alerts' );` I corrected your answer. Thanks again